# Why when I upload a file to my website, the extension is change to .bin?

Tags: 18.04, server

I have my website in sumfony, put into production on an Ubuntu 18.04 server in Digital Ocean, everything works fine until I try to process some file, be it image or xlsx (Excel). When uploading the extension is changed to .bin and I don't know why.

I would appreciate any help in advance. Regards

Comment: Welcome! The site is english only. Can you provide a translation?

Comment: Hello Sean Luis. I have translated your question, so you can get some better answers and better support. It will be useful if you explain exactly what are you doing and also explain what is "Digital Ocean" and "Sumfony". I didn't translate it because of it may be correct but I guess you meant "Symphony". The details are important to receive the proper support. Don't forget to add your details by editing your question or dropping a comment on this question. **Not an answer, please**.